# How to use OnselectedIndexChange without postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have 2 dropdown lists and I need the first one (ActionList) to control the values of the second one (JustificationList). The issue is when I include the Autopostback on the first dropdown, my whole page refreshed.

I tried using an updatePanel and a trigger but It still doesn't work. There are no errors, only that the refresh happens on Index Changed.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">             
    <ContentTemplate>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text"
            placeholder="Search.." autocomplete="off" style="width: 80%; 
            margin-left: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px;">

        <asp:Label Text="Update Selection" runat="server" Style="width: 80%; 
            margin-left: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: white"></asp:Label>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ActionList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            CSSclass="form-control" style="width: 80%; margin-left: 25px; 
            margin-bottom: 10px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="JustificationData">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="JustificationList" runat="server" 
            CSSclass="form-control"  style="width: 80%; margin-left: 25px; 
            margin-bottom: 10px;">
        </asp:DropDownList>    
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ActionList" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Postback are mandatory with `runat="server"` controls. Consider using client side dropdown control.

Comment: Technically, the whole page *posts back*, but only the content inside the update panel refreshes when the postback is triggered by a control inside the panel (or trigger). P.S. you don't need a trigger if the postback control is inside the update panel.

Comment: Is there a reason why my trigger is not working? both my dropdowns are on the updatePanel. If I remove the postback, the second dropdown doesn't load.